# Selecionando classe com jquery

Tags: jquery

Qual a diferença em selecionar a classe dessas duas maneiras em `JQUERY`?

Uma tem acesso a parâmetros, outra não, como funciona ?

```
var valor = $(".classe");
var valorAnime = 'classe';
```

Da uma olhada nesse código :

```
 (function(){
 let $target =$(".projeto"),
    animeStart = 'projeto-anime',
    offset = $(window).height() * 3/4;

    function animeScroll (){
        let documentTop = $(document).scrollTop();

        $target.each(function(){
            let itemTop = $(this).offset().top;

            if( documentTop > itemTop - offset) {
                $(this).addClass(animeStart);
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass(animeStart);
            }
        }) 
    }

 animeScroll();

 $(document).scroll(function(){
     animeScroll();

 });
 }());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao meu ponto de vista, quando você faz

```
var valor = $(".classe");
```

você está buscando na página o objeto cuja classe corresponde a `classe`, já quando voce utiliza esse código.

```
var valorAnime = 'classe';
```

você está atribuindo à variável `valorAnime` uma string cujo o conteúdo é *classe*

**EDITADO:**

bom esse segundo código seu faz a seguinte coisa;

```
let $target =$(".projeto"),
```

prende o que tem classe *projeto*

dentro do loop que ele tá fazendo sobre os objetos de `$target`, depois de verificar na condicional do `if` ele utiliza o `$(this)` que nada mais é o objeto que está sendo iterado, e adiciona a ele uma classe com o comando `addClass` onde o nome da classe é *projeto-anime*

Se não me engano funcionaria da mesma forma se voce fizesse:

```
            if( documentTop > itemTop - offset) {
                $(this).addClass('projeto-anime');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('projeto-anime');
            }
```

Mas por questões de modularização, é melhor utilizar da forma como você apresentou primeiro. Espero que tenha sido claro

Comment: Da uma olhada no código que adicionei. Compreendi sua explicação, mas da forma que esse código está ele tem acesso a classe projeto-anime que tá no css e a função é executada sem erros, caso eu selecione a classe da mesma forma que selecionei a primeira, da erro. Não to conseguindo entender justamente essa segunda forma que foi utilizada para selecionar a classe.

Comment: Dei uma editada na minha resposta para adequar a pergunta, espero que tenha sido claro e que você tenha compreendido o que está acontecendo

Comment: sim, sim. obrigado!